# Word add-in: Getting user credentials which were used to open the document from SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-word, add-in

We are developing a Word add-in on C# and WPF.

The documents are opened from SharePoint that lives in another domain, and are processed using add-in. 
When the document is opened, MS Word asks for credentials for SharePoint domain.

In Word Add-in, I need to retrieve these credentials, or any security token, to inteoperate with SharePoint.

When I try to use CredentialsCache from C#, I get the credentials for local windows/domain account, but not the Sharepoint domain account.

I understand that Word stores credentials for SharePoint, as I can check-in/check-out and save without re-entering password.

But can I somehow get these credentials from code to access SharePoint services without re-prompting password?

Answer (score 1):

If the web service being invoked uses windows integrated security, creating a NetworkCredential from the current WindowsIdentity should be sufficient to allow the web service to use the current users windows login. However, if the web service uses a different security model, there isn't any way to extract a users password from the current identity...that in and of itself would be insecure, allowing you, the developer, to steal your users passwords. You will likely need to provide some way for your user to provide their password, and keep it in some secure cache if you don't want them to have to repeatedly provide it.

Edit: To get the credentials for the current identity, use the following:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
```